# Django PolygonField - How to display on map?

Tags: django-templates, polygon

**How do I retrieve the value of this polygonfield from database and display it as a polygon on a map in my template?**

**Model**

```
class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Property(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
polygon = models.PolygonField()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

**View**

```
def profile(request, username):
user = get_object_or_404(User,username=username)

instance = Property.objects.filter(user=user)
category_list = Category.objects.all()

context = {
    'instance': instance,
    'categories': category_list,
}
return render(request, 'maps/profile.html', context)
```